# How to get calendar ID for an event when making Get Event call?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

On creating a new `event` in a user's calendar, I receive a push notification that contains the `id` of the newly created event. In order to get more details about this event, I make the [Get Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-get?view=graph-rest-1.0) call:

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-get?view=graph-rest-1.0
```

This returns all the event details for that particular event, but it does not seem to be returning the `id` of the `calendar` in which the event was created. I need it to attach this event to existing calendar in my local cache.

I have looked at the API spec but do not see calendar id field anywhere.

I would like to get an idea on how to get calendar id after making a get event call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [relationship](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0#relationships) of `Event` resource with `Calendar` resource and Microsoft Graph lets you query relationships of one resource with another via [`expand` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#expand-parameter).

In case of `Event` resource its properties along with *associated* `Calendar` properties within a single query could be requested like this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/{event-id}/?$expand=calendar
```

The response will contain among another properties the `Id` of Calendar

**References**

[Use query parameters to customize responses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters)